# Why Elasticsearch Arabic analyzer comes alongside Persian analyzer in the Persian examples?

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently checked the language analyzer in elasticsearch docs and wonder why in this example: [analysis-lang-analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#persian-analyzer) the Persian analyzer comes after the Arabic analyzer?! Is that needed because of anything? I mean the Persian analyzer alone, is not enough for the Persian language?

> Persian analyzer The Persian analyzer could be reimplemented as a
> custom analyzer as follows:

```
PUT /persian_example
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "zero_width_spaces": {
            "type":       "mapping",
            "mappings": [ "\\u200C=>\\u0020"] 
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "persian_stop": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwords":  "_persian_" 
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt_persian": {
          "tokenizer":     "standard",
          "char_filter": [ "zero_width_spaces" ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "decimal_digit",
            "arabic_normalization",
            "persian_normalization",
            "persian_stop"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @OpsterElasticsearchNinja , it was very helpful. but I didn't get my answer. The thing is they are doing different things and recently I figured out that maybe having Arabic and Persian together in the Analyzer field is a better idea for the Persian language. In my case what the Persian Analyzer does was not enough.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its required, you can index few sentences by removing the `arabic_normalization` and use the [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to check the tokens generated by persian analyzer and see if it generates the correct expected tokens.

You can also open the issue on elastic repo https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues which is the best place to ask this question as there someone from elastic can comment whether its a documentation issue or some real issue.

Answer (score 1):

this analyzer are made by Lucene Users and forum. you should check what arabic_normalization do in lucene and is it necessary?

this is arabic_normalization class description:

> Normalizer for Arabic.
>
> Normalization is defined as:
>
> Normalization of hamza with alef seat to a bare alef.
>
> Normalization of teh marbuta to heh
>
> Normalization of dotless yeh (alef maksura) to yeh.
>
> Removal of Arabic diacritics (the harakat) Removal of tatweel
> (stretching character).

(as I know Persian) I think it is better for Persian indexing that you first use Arabic Normalizer